# How to prompt user to enter multiple values on the same line?

Tags: c, scanf

How can we have a user enter three different values on the same line.
Something like this: `enter three numbers: 1, 2, 3` but all three will be stored in 3 different variables.
I tried doing something this like this:

```
 printf("Enter three numbers: ");
 scanf("%d %d %d", one,two,three);
```

But this does not work!

Here is the entire code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {

        int one,two,three;

        printf("Enter three numbers: ");
        scanf("%d %d %d", &one,&two,&three);

        printf("%d %d %d \n", one,two,three);
}
```

I tried entering `1, 2, 3` and I got this: `1 134513881 -1218503675`

Comment: "Does not work." How so?

Comment: @owacoder, it's not obvious to you?

Comment: @owacoder the program gives segmentation fault

Comment: @Blindy - We don't know how `one`, `two`, and `three` are declared, do we?

Comment: I tried that code you posted @8:39GMT and it works fine. What's the problem? What exactly is the problem? Exactly what numbers did you try when you ran it? As long as you aren't entering numbers larger than an `int` can hold, it should be fine.

Comment: @lurker I want to enter the all 3 numbers on the same line separated by commas like this: Enter the numbers: 1, 2, 3.

Comment: I tried 1, 2, 3 and I got this: 1 134513881 -1218503675

Comment: Well of course, your `scanf` is looking for spaces between the numbers and the format string says nothing about commas. You could do `scanf("%d, %d, %d", &one, &two, &three);` but it's going to be specific about spacing (no space between the number and following comma - `1, 2, 3` would work, as would, `1,2,3` but not `1 , 2 , 3`). More generally, it's better to read the line in and parse it at that point to ensure whatever results you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the number are to be separated by commas as in the example, the commas need to be part of the format string. Check the return of scanf to confirm three fields were input.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int one = 0,two = 0,three = 0, ch = 0;

    printf("Enter three numbers separated by commas: ");
    while ( ( scanf("%d ,%d ,%d", &one, &two, &three)) != 3) {
        printf("Please enter three numbers separated by commas: ");
        while ( ( ch = getchar ( )) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
            //clear input buffer
        }
    }
    printf("%d %d %d \n", one,two,three);
    return 0;
}
```

As commented by @M.M, the scanf format `"%d ,%d ,%d"` with a space before the comma will allow the commas to be preceded by any amount of whitespace (including none) to allow input of `1,2,3` or `1 , 2,3`. `%d` also skips any leading whitespace.

Comment: It should also be explained that the placement of commas in the format string is important here: `" ,"` instead of just `","` means that any amount of whitespace (including none) will be read and discarded before the comma.  The `%d` format specifier also does that, so this string can cope with `1, 2, 3` and `1  ,   2,3`.

Answer (score 3):

```
scanf("%d %d %d", &one, &two, &three);
```

You were close, but `scanf` doesn't care about the value of those variables (which is great, because they're most likely not initialized), it cares about their addresses so it can dereference them and write inside.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but when I enter three different number it gives some negative and long numbers like this: -10864473763

Comment: Post your entire code to see what you did wrong, I'm not a crystal ball.